# How to simplify and rationalize use of IIS Express when wanting to copy Projects and Solutions, or manage on different machines?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I am looking for some best practices ideas (and perhaps simpler mechanisms) of keeping IIS Express ports, both SSL and non-SSL, sanely and neatly managed within a team-based development environment where we may also be copying templates of MVC projects to create new projects.

We are building numerous MVC applications within my company, which are then deployed on various web servers for clients of ours.

IIS Express is great when developing a new MVC app, and debugging it.  And subsequent deployment to a "real" web server is no problem.

Problem comes about when copying a Solution with an MVC app to create a new solution (ie new MVC app) based on the old one.  I can copy the solution, I can open it in Visual Studio, but (of course) the selected IIS Express ports for non-SSL access and SSL access are the same as in the source application.  This is a recipe for disaster, of course, as I want to branch my copy away from the original to create a new app.

I have found suggestions on how to change the IIExpress Server by simply right clicking on the app properties, going to the "Web" tab and modifying the port there.  However, that is error prone and almost always involves ALSO needing to edit the IISExpress applicationhost.config file manually.

This problem is compounded when there are two (or more) developers sharing development tasks on these MVC apps as they may have frustratingly overlapping IISExpress ports.

Any experiences that can make this less painful?  I feel like I am just wrestling with the IDE and TFS in ways that can't be intended.

Thanks in advance for ideas or pointers to resources that may help.